# How to call the closing price of other stocks in Pine Script?

Tags: trading

I want to include in the indicator code the closing prices of several different stocks in a comparison, but I don't know how to refer to the closing prices of these other stocks. what function would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 5):

The function you are looking for is called `security`. [Here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_security) is the reference.

For an example:
If you want to retrieve the close price of `BTC/USD` on `biance` you use the `security` function like

```
btc_close = nz(security("binance:BTCUSDT", timeframe.period, close))
```

The function `nz` replaces NaN values with zeros.